# Can I do a "Complete PC Backup" in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, backup

I had an older SSD that I installed Windows 8 on while waiting for a newer, larger SSD. I'd like to move the OS onto the larger SSD.

Windows Vista and Windows 7 came with a "Complete PC Backup" feature which essentially created a disk image, which could be restored using Windows installation media.

Does this feature still exist in Windows 8? If so, how can I access it?

Comment: You could have deleted the question immediately after figuring out it was a duplicate, but of course now there's an answer you can't do so.

Comment: @Karan: Yes, but that would keep people searching for "Complete PC Backup" from finding the duplicate. I'd rather point people looking for that feature name to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it still exists, as you've commented.

Alternatively you could use dd in a linux terminal to do a full sector by sector copy of the drive.

Comment: dd would be inconvenient because the source drive is bitlocker'd.

Comment: That was not mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 0):

the backup will be removed from 8.1, so buy a 3rd party tool. MSFT now recommends to use Refresh + File History as backup.

**Windows 7 Backup and Restore deprecated**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Erm, why would it be removed in 8.1? That source doesn't indicate anything like that -- just that no updates were done in 8. I don't see them nuking whole features like that in a minor point release.

Comment: Install the 8.1 Preview and you no longer find the entries.

Comment: Interesting. Well that really sucks. :(